# Firebase Flutter Does Not Recognize My String as Parameter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to get user email,save to shared preferences and use as collection name in another file.

my code to save

```
Future<void> saveEmail() async {
var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
sharedPreferences.setString("email", _emailKontroller.text);}
```

no problem here, I can save data to sharedPreferences and read data from another file.

my code to read

```
  @override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
void initilaizeEmail() async {
  var sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  _email = sharedPreferences.getString("email");
  print(_email);
}

initilaizeEmail();
setState(() {});
```

}

output

> I/flutter ( 3274): a@a.com

where I use as parameter my sharedPreferences Data:

```
 query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("test")
        .doc("$_email")
        .collection("class 0"),
    // to fetch real-time data
    isLive: false,
```

I can not see anything on screen but, if I delete

> _email

and type "a@a.com" manually everything works.What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with using

> Future Builder

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `initilaizeEmail` is an `async` method, and you're not waiting for its result. To fix this:

```
await initilaizeEmail();
```

I also recommend fixing the name of the method to be `initializeEmail`. While it won't change the behavior, spelling mistakes tend distract from other problems.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Frank, I decided to use future builder to create more readable code.